# Why JSON is faster to clone an object than `for in` and `map`?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, copy, clone

Using the functions below to deeply clone a tree,

```
function clone_map(obj){
    return obj.map(function(val){
        return typeof(val) == "object" ? clone_map(val) : val;
    });
};
function clone_forin(obj){
    var result = [];
    for (var key in obj){
        var val = obj[key];
        result.push(typeof(val) == "object" ? clone_forin(val) : val);
    };
    return result;
};
function clone_json(obj){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
};
```

The JSON one is the fastest [on my tests](http://jsperf.com/treedeepclonejsonvsfunction). Why? And is there a better option?

Comment: because arrays are easily serialized. the `forin` solution is faster when working with objects instead of arrays: http://jsperf.com/treedeepclonejsonvsfunction/2

Comment: Note that someone has tested it on Safari, and found that it's *not* faster. In fact, JSON is the slowest (on Safari). So it's fastest on Chrome and slowest on Safari. Probably be a mix in other browsers as well. So there's really no question to answer here.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - That was me :) I think the browser used could be a factor. Which one are you using? In Safari `clone_map()` is much faster than the others.

Comment: Your tests are mis-labelled. The JSON test is the JSON test, but the other two labels are swapped.

Comment: It should be noted that the `clone_map` and `clone_forin` functions in these examples do not test for circular references.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from subsequent tests, the JSON option is faster on some versions of Chrome, but not on Safari or Firefox. You'll probably find a mix in other browsers as well.

Your JavaScript cloning code is in JavaScript. A browser is free to implement `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` in highly optimized machine code. (It's also free to compile your JavaScript into optimized machine code if it feels it needs to.) So it's no great surprise that *sometimes*, a fairly simple array such as the one you tested with might be faster via JSON than not. On some engines. With some sets of sample data. And that on other engines (or with other sets of sample data), there's a different result.

It's also worth noting that the difference isn't massive, not in any real world sense. The JSON option is about 25% faster than its nearest competitor in the tests shown in Chrome 24. But each individual iteration is so blindingly fast that it makes no real-world difference. 392k ops/sec vs. 521k ops/sec, it's still a shedload of ops/sec. :-)